# Sequelize query randomly hanging

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, sequelize.js, generator

I am calling a method that updates some data in a Postgres model using Sequelize. The call is from within an async generator function as follows:

Folder Structure:

1. folder1

   - initialCallFile (generator funtion)
   - anotherFileThatCalls (non-generator function)
2. folder2

   - updateBotMethodFile

Initial Call:

```
async function* function() {
    await storage.updateBot({id: player.id, handsPlayed: 1, isActive: true});
}
```

updateBot Method:

```
function updateBot(data) {
  return new Promise(async resolve => {
    try {
      const bot = await Bot.findOne({
        where: {
          id: data.id,
        },
      });

      if (bot) {
        if (data.handsPlayed)
          bot.handsPlayed += data.handsPlayed;
        if (data.handsWon)
          bot.handsWon += data.handsWon;
        if (data.totalWinnings)
          bot.totalWinnings = data.totalWinnings;
        if (data.isActive !== null && data.isActive !== undefined)
          bot.isActive = data.isActive;
      } else {
        logger.log('debug', 'No Bot found with id: %s', data.id);
        resolve(true);
      }

      await bot.save();

      resolve(true);
    } catch (err) {
      logger.log('error', 'Error updating Bot with id: %s', data.id);
      resolve(true);
    }
  });
}
```

The updateBot method is hanging at the initial Bot.fineOne query. There are no errors thrown, and even after 5-10 minutes, there is no timeout.

I am calling updateBot from other places as well that are not from within a generator function and they work as expected without hanging. However I do not think it is the generator function causing the issues since for one it is a totally separate function, and when I replace the query with a simple timeout it does not hang.

I have also tried calling the update directly within my generator function as well as using yield instead of await and there is still a hang. Since there are no errors or timeout I am not sure how best to debug the issue. The code works as intended when called elsewhere, so I am quite stumped.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a generator? Shouldn't a simple await function be enough to do the job?

Comment: Also, updateBot can be an await function and return results directly, you don't need to create a Promise inside